# Not receiving post data from amp-form

Tags: javascript, php, amp-html

So I'm trying to set up an amp-form that acts as a fronter to a larger normal form but I need to capture the data from the amp-form as well for our segmented & analytics data. I'm attempting to do this with a middle page that the amp form posts to that will capture and forward the data then forwards the user and their data to the full form.

I set up the amp form, the simplified code is as follows (simplified to one field to post here, but tested and same issue):

```
<form class="amp-lead-form" method="post" action-xhr="<?php get_site_url() ?>/submit-amp-form.php" target="_top" custom-validation-reporting="show-first-on-submit">
  <fieldset style="border: none;">
    <label>
      <input class="text_input" type="text"
             id="first_name"
             name="first_name"
             placeholder="First Name"
             required
             pattern="([a-zA-ZàáâäãåąčćęèéêëėįìíîïłńòóôöõøùúûüųūÿýżźñçčšžÀÁÂÄÃÅĄĆČĖĘÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏĮŁŃÒÓÔÖÕØÙÚÛÜŲŪŸÝŻŹÑßÇŒÆČŠŽ∂ð,.'-])\w+">
      <span visible-when-invalid="valueMissing"
                validation-for="first_name"><br>Please enter your first name.</span>
      <span visible-when-invalid="patternMismatch"
            validation-for="first_name">
         <br>Please enter just your first name.</span>
    </label>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <input class="amp-form-submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="GET STARTED">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

The middle-page code is as follows (this is bare bones to test the form, security and all that other stuff I need will be added once I get the data figured out):

```
<?php
require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-load.php' );
$domain_url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://".get_site_url();

header("Content-type: application/json"); //I also tried with multipart/form-data and application/x-www-form-urlencoded
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ". str_replace('.', '-',get_site_url()) .".cdn.ampproject.org");
header("AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin: " . get_site_url());
header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin");
header("AMP-Redirect-To: ".get_site_url()."/submit-amp-form.php");
header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AMP-Redirect-To, AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin");

//dump data to page so I can view
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
var_dump($data);
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

Right now the middle page only displays the data so I can see that it's being sent properly but what displays is:

```
DATA: 
string(0) ""
array(0) {
}
```

Which tells me the data isn't being sent or recieved properly. When I change the method of the form to get and action-xhr to action it does send and recieve the get data. I researched the internet and found that usually this means the endpoint isn't implementing CORS security but I believe I have all the required headers on the page so I really don't know where to go from here. Any help?

Comment: if you have got this working, could you please share the working code as an answer....it will help everyone...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it's a CORS issue you would see errors appearing in the console of your browser hinting you to CORS.
Have you checked that? Your console should give you a good hint where the error is.
I'm guessing you're not getting an acceptable response from your endpoint.
This might be due to your var_dumps at the end.

Comment: I got it figured out thanks. It's because I had the AMP-Redirect-To set to the same page as the endpoint, which meant I got redirected twice, the second time losing the post data.